# Add style or class to element onRouteUpdate on Gatsby

Tags: javascript, gatsby

I have a nav bar, and I need change color (add class) to this on every page that's not homepage (/).

I try many options I think the best is on gatsby-browser.js or gatsby-ssr.js

I need put every page is not home page.

Below is my gatsby-browser.js

```
import { globalHistory } from "@reach/router"

globalHistory.listen(({ location }) => {

  if(location.pathname !== "/"){
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      document.getElementById("navbar").classList.add("navbar-interns")
    });
  }

})
```

Any solution to do this?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @ksav no! I do a new navbar to internal pages and put on every page... can check this links [link](https://spectrum.chat/gatsby-js/general/add-style-or-class-to-element-onrouteupdate-on-gatsby~f027cba0-139c-4cd9-93f4-ce7a0b0e7fd4)

Answer (score 1):

Try passing `location` as a prop to your Navbar component from each page component.

```
// ./components/navbar.js

import React from "react"

const Navbar = ({ location }) => {
  const rootPath = `${__PATH_PREFIX__}/`
  let navBarClassName
  if (location.pathname === rootPath) {
    navBarClassName = "navbar--homepage"
    return <div className={navBarClassName}>my homepage navbar stuff</div>
  } else {
    navBarClassName = "navbar--other"
    return <div className={navBarClassName}>my other navbar stuff</div>
  }
}

export default Navbar
```

---

```
// ./pages/index.js

import React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import Navbar from "../components/navbar"

const IndexPage = ({ location }) => (
    <>
        <Navbar location={location} />
        <Link to="/page-2/">Go to page 2</Link>
    </>
)

export default IndexPage
```

---

```
// ./pages/page-2.js

import React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"

import Navbar from "../components/navbar"

const SecondPage = ({ location }) => (
    <>
        <Navbar location={location} />
        <Link to="/">Go back to the homepage</Link>
    </>
)

export default SecondPage
```

[image: Edit rough-sound-ur7p9]

Comment: Sorry but: TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined
on line: if (Location.pathname === rootPath) {

I try to import (import { Location } from '@reach/router';) location from route, but error still.

Comment: `location` not `Location`

Comment: My page use layout.js kinda like this:

`// layout.js
<Layout>
   <Nav />
   {children}
</Layout>`

`// index.js
<Layout>
   /* Page content here */
</Layout>`

My code is here https://github.com/johanguse/space-joyjet

Comment: If you are using a class component you need to do `this.props.location`